# Bootstrap 3: Collapsable Menu's z-Index

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, menu, z-index, collapsable

My test site is at this [link](http://history.clmitchell.net/)...

When the page width is below 768px, how do I get the  navicon menu to show properly above everything else?

Following are my navbar and colornavbar css files:

---start navbar.css--

```
    /* <nav> tag, classes: navbar & navbar-default */
.navbar{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.navbar-default{
    background:#317ca2;
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #3f94bf, #246485);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #3f94bf, #246485);
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #3f94bf, #246485);
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #3f94bf), color-stop(1, #246485));
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(#3f94bf, #246485);
    background:linear-gradient(top, #3f94bf, #246485);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 5px rgba(34,34,34,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 5px rgba(34,34,34,0.5);
    box-shadow:0 1px 5px rgba(34,34,34,0.5);
    width:100%;
    max-width:none;
    height:50px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #1b5572;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
  }

a.navbar-brand{
    color: white;
}

/* <ul> tag, classes: nav & navbar-nav */

/* Collapsed menu links */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: white;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: yellow;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
     .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

}
```

--end colornavbar.css--

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated after your update code,  just change your `@media` like this in your `navbar.css`

```
@media (max-width: 767px) { /*-- Change max-width from 768 to 767 --*/
 .navbar-header {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
/*.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
}*/  /*-- Disable this, suggest remove - this cause the menu disappear as soon as it toogle in --*/
.navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;
    margin: 7.5px -15px;
    position:relative;  /*-- New attribute --*/
    z-index:9999;   /*-- New attribute --*/
    background-color:#393939;  /*-- New attribute --*/
}
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

}

Hope this help!

Comment: I tried that both inside and out side of the @media (width:768px) block...no change.

Comment: that wierd, i tried direct in inspector mode and it work like [this](http://s11.postimg.org/om9a973yr/Capture.jpg) ; or let's try change your media to `@media (max-width: 768px)` with my class above inside and tell me the result

Comment: completely ignores it (thanks for your time and attention, BTW).

Comment: nah, i think it must work ( [tested](http://s27.postimg.org/xqz3a3o5v/Capture.jpg) again within your code), not sure what wrong

Comment: I'm sorry! It must be me.

Comment: Ive added the two navbar css files i have linked. I'll go through them myself as well and try to eliminate any duplicates.

Comment: can you send me the whole project (html, css, js ...) to `archangelhero47@gmail.com` so i can test myself, can't know what wrong when the situation so wierd like this :)

Comment: That's very kind of you...give me a few minutes!

Comment: I've tried a few examples from the web. The main thing I've noticed is that, with the inclusion of DataTables I've gone from jquery 1.11.x to 2.x...?

Comment: Henry, your fixed worked! Can you post the corrected navbar.css on your answer, or do you wish for me to post the answer?